# Как сравнить элементы в списке?

Tags: python, алгоритм

**Доброго времени суток**, друзья,

У меня вопрос. Вот есть список:

```
a = [('германия', ), ('германия', ), ('япония', )]
```

Как сравнить список так, что если попадаются две одинаковые страны, то удалять одну из них?

И еще желательно как убрать лишние символы, но это другое)

list.set(a) почему-то не работает

Comment: а ты это из базы получаешь?

Comment: да. это все flask

Comment: тогда дублирующиеся строки можно было бы сразу убрать с помощью DISTINCT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> list.set(a) почему-то не работает

Потому что у типа `list` не существует метода `set()`. Вместо этого предлагаю просто обернуть `set(a)` в `list()` — программа самостоятельно превратит множество (без повторяющихся элементов) в список:

```py
a = [('германия', ), ('германия', ), ('япония', )]
print(list(set(a)))

-----

[('япония',), ('германия',)]
```

Comment: отлично, действительно помогло! спасибо!! осталось узнать как убрать лишние символы

Comment: @uw935 о каких лишних символах идёт речь? Можете конкретизировать?

Comment: лишние символы типа: скобки, кавычки, запятые: (),''

Comment: @uw935 Это не "лишние" символы. Кавычки показывают, что это строка. Запятая в скобках - что там кортеж. Чтобы превратить этот список в планарный, можно сделать `a = [x[0] for x in a]` или `a = list(list(zip(*a))[0])` или `a = list(sum(a, ()))`.

Comment: @GrAnd получилось!)) спасибо огромное ))